# Plotting the percentage of series of variables which are multilevel (side by side)

Tags: r, dataframe, ggplot2, dplyr

I am trying to plot a series of variables, which are collected in two-time frames. The structure of data is something like this. Please see the structure of the data.

```
n<-structure(list(sitime_1 = structure(c(2L, 4L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
4L, 1L, 4L, 3L, 1L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 4L), .Label = c("0", 
"More than 1 year ago", "Within the past year", "Within the past month"
), class = "factor"), sitime_2 = structure(c(1L, 4L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 4L, 1L, 3L, 4L, 1L, 4L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 1L
), .Label = c("0", "More than 1 year ago", "Within the past year", 
"Within the past month"), class = "factor"), sitime_3 = structure(c(1L, 
4L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 4L, 1L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
3L, 3L, 4L), .Label = c("0", "More than 1 year ago", "Within the past year", 
"Within the past month"), class = "factor"), wave = c("secon", 
"first", "secon", "first", "secon", "first", "secon", "first", 
"secon", "first", "secon", "first", "secon", "first", "secon", 
"first", "secon", "first", "secon", "first")), row.names = c(NA, 
-20L), class = c("data.table", "data.frame"))
```

```
                 sitime_1              sitime_2              sitime_3  wave
 1:  More than 1 year ago                     0                     0 secon
 2: Within the past month Within the past month Within the past month first
 3:                     0                     0                     0 secon
 4:                     0                     0                     0 first
 5:                     0                     0                     0 secon
 6:                     0                     0                     0 first
 7: Within the past month                     0                     0 secon
 8:                     0                     0                     0 first
 9: Within the past month Within the past month                     0 secon
10:  Within the past year                     0                     0 first
11:                     0  Within the past year                     0 secon
12: Within the past month Within the past month Within the past month first
13: Within the past month                     0                     0 secon
14: Within the past month Within the past month  Within the past year first
15:                     0                     0                     0 secon
16:  Within the past year                     0                     0 first
17:  Within the past year  Within the past year                     0 secon
18:  Within the past year  Within the past year  Within the past year first
19:  Within the past year  Within the past year  Within the past year secon
20: Within the past month                     0 Within the past month first
```

I need to get the percentage in y a-axis, and I have used this code:

```
n <- pivot_longer(n, cols = starts_with("si"))
n$wave<-as.factor(n$wave)
n$value<-as.factor(n$value)

n$wave_and_name <- as.factor(paste(n$wave,n$name, sep="_"))
n <- as.data.frame(table(filter(n, value != 0)$wave_and_name) / table(n$wave_and_name) * 100)


n$wave <- substr(n$Var1, 1, 5)

n$name <- substr(n$Var1, 7, 14)


ggplot(n, aes(x=name, y=Freq)) +
  geom_bar(aes(fill = wave), stat="identity",position = position_dodge()) +
  xlab("sit") + 
  ylab("percent")+ggtitle("Sit")
```

However, instead of getting several levels, I get this[image: Just one level instead of more levels]

Please help me how to solve this issue.

Comment: Could you tell us a little more about what the desired plot will look like?

Comment: Do you want to get the distribution (percentages) of responses in each sittime_1,2,3? 
All these, within each wave?

Comment: This is exactly I want

Comment: I need (percentages) of responses in each sittime_1,2,3. For instance, what is the percentage of people who answered More than 1 year ago in each wave. Also Within the past month, and  Within the past year. The format is exactly what I provide in my question but include all the levels. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe you are looking for this:

```
library(tidyverse)
#Code
n %>% pivot_longer(-wave) %>%
  filter(value!='0') %>%
  group_by(name,wave,value) %>%
  summarise(N=n()) %>%
  group_by(name,wave,.drop = T) %>%
  mutate(Perc=N/sum(N)) %>%
  ggplot(aes(x=name,y=Perc,fill=value))+
  geom_bar(stat = 'identity',
           position = position_dodge2(0.9,preserve = 'single'))+
  facet_wrap(.~wave,scales = 'free')+
  scale_y_continuous(labels = scales::percent)
```

Output:

[image]